# Go json.Marshal unable get single backslash

Tags: json, go, marshalling

```golang
var (
    username        string = "ADuser\\user"
    password         string = "PASS"
    userCredentials        = map[string]string{"username": username, "password": password}
)

func main() {
   jsonValue, _ := json.Marshal(userCredentials)
   ...
}
```

If i try print marshal value I get this output

```golang
fmt.Println(string(jsonValue))
   Output:
      {"password":"PASS","username":"ADuser\\user"}
```

But if I try print only username I get this output

```golang
fmt.Println(username)
    Output:
      ADuser\user
```

I need this output:

```golang
fmt.Println(string(jsonValue))
   Output:
      {"password":"PASS","username":"ADuser\user"}
```

I tried use ascii code but I get same output. Have some ideas how i can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is as it should be. The backslash is a special character in JSON, and if a string should contain a backslash, in the JSON representation it has to be escaped, which is to double it.

Your username in the JSON text holds the value `ADuser\user`, but in JSON it has to be represented with double backslash.

You will see it if you decode it:

```
var decoded map[string]string
if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonValue, &decoded); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(decoded)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nh0KsGgZvCS)):

```
map[password:PASS username:ADuser\user]
```

Comment: But i need send marshal value to API post 


request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", URL, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonValue))


But if I send this request to remote API, I get error with authorization, because I get username which contain double backslash.

Comment: @JakubJastrabík In your Go source you wrote: `username string = "ADuser\\user"`. You wrote 2 backslashes, because that means one backslash. The same goes with JSON: 2 backslashes mean one backslash. If you get an authorization error, it's for something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot for response.